# How to move element without changing the page height?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to move an element up the page without changing the height of the page.

How do I do this?

At the moment `minus margin-top` and `margin-bottom` move the element but page height is increased/deceased too.

Html:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div><div id="text-7" 
class="widget widget_text"><div 
class="textwidget"><div 
class="line-down">
<div class="line-down1">
<div class="line-down1">
<div class="line-down1">
<div class="line-down1">
```

Css:

Tried:

```
#text-7 {margin-bottom: 500px;}
```

Also

```
#text-7 {margin-top: -500px;}
```

Element moves but page size gets bigger, or am I just changing page size here whilst the element appears to move?

See [here](http://4309.co.uk)

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but it sounds like `position:absolute;` is what you're looking for. `margin-bottom` is what is causing the page height to increase.

Comment: So. `#text-7 {margin-top: -Xpx; position: absolute;} `?

Comment: `position: absolute; top: -Xpx`; read about css `position`

Comment: You don't need `margin-top` at all when using `position:absolute;` you will just set the `top`/`left` values to position it.

Comment: @APAD1  I thought `top` was just short for `margin-top`?

Comment: @APAD1 it worked though. Thanks

Comment: You can learn [more about position here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp), you may need to contain the `absolute` positioned element within a `relative` positioned element depending on what you're trying to do. [`top`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp) is not the same as [`margin-top`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-top.asp). You will also most likely need to specify a height on the element since you don't have anything inside the element that would define the height.

Comment: To move an element without affecting anything else, you use `position: relative`.

Comment: @ APAD1 Thanks. It did kinda work but now I've got a random box shadow covering half the text in mobile view at http://4309.co.uk. Is that a result of position: relative;?

Comment: Position:absolute I mean?